# Quadratic Equation Solver in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a simple quadratic equation solver in C#, but for some reason it's not quite giving me the correct answers. In fact, it's giving me extremely large numbers as answers, usually well into the millions.

Could anyone please shed some light? I get the exact same answer for the positive root and the negative root as well. (Tried two different methods of math)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;

        Console.WriteLine("Hi, this is a Quadratic Equation Solver!");
        Console.WriteLine("a-value: ");
        try
        {
            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("b-value: ");
            b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("c-value: ");
            c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Okay, so your positive root is: " + quadForm(a, b, c, true));
            Console.WriteLine("And your negative root is: " + quadForm(a, b, c, false));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int quadForm(int a, int b, int c, Boolean pos)
    {
        int x = 0;
        if (pos)
            x = ((-b + (int) (Math.Sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))) / (2 * a));
        else
            x = ((-Math.Abs(b) - (int) (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c)))) / (2 * a));
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: What inputs are you giving it?

Comment: @Asad I tried 1, 2, 3, respectively for a, b, c, and got an output of... 1073741823 for both roots

Comment: @user3924098, do you know what is the result of `(b * b) - (4 * a * c)` for your a,b,c being 1,2,3?

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, the result is -8.

Comment: @user3924098, can you also tell me what is the square root of `-8`? Or more specifically, what is the return value of `Math.Sqrt(-8)`?

Comment: Looks to met that this question should be asked on some other site first - SO is not the best place to get answers to math questions.

Comment: @elgonzo So I tried 
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sqrt(-8).ToString()); 
and it gave me 'NaN'

Comment: @user3924098 Check this link for what happens when you convert `double.NaN` (the return of `Math.Sqrt()` for a negative) to an int: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639860/why-does-casting-a-nan-to-a-long-yield-a-valid-result

Comment: `(int)Math.Sqrt(-8)` will produce `-2147483648`

Comment: @user3924098, in case you wonder what 'NaN' stands for; it means "Not a Number"...

Comment: Ah, I see. So I should add a check for negative square roots. Let me try that?

Comment: What's with the `Math.Abs()` call?

Comment: @TavianBarnes I was googling how to make the b negative, and I came across that. But I think just -b will suffice?

Comment: @user3924098, i am not sure what kind of equation you want to solve. If it is the simple `a * x^2 + b * x + c = 0`, then the roots for (a,b,c) being (1,2,3) are complex numbers. Bog-standard integer or floating point functions cannot give you complex number results; you would rather need to work with the [System.Numerics.Complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.aspx) type...

Comment: Don't cast the result of `Sqrt` to an integer. Just because the coefficients are integers it doesn't mean the roots are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this version of `quadForm`:

```
static double quadForm(int a, int b, int c, bool pos)
{
    var preRoot = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (preRoot < 0)
    {
        return double.NaN;
    }
    else
    {
        var sgn = pos ? 1.0 : -1.0;
        return (sgn * Math.Sqrt(preRoot) - b) / (2.0 * a);
    }
}
```

Comment: The schoolbook version of the quadratic formula has potential problems with severe loss of precision.  Suggest using the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance#A_better_algorithm

Comment: @dbc - There's a difference between a "severe" and "significant". This also only affects situations where two numbers that are relatively close together are subtracted. This isn't generally an issue. So unless this code needs engineering precision it shouldn't be a problem.